# HTML CSS ASPTable "bugged"?

Tags: c#, html, css, .net, bootstrap-4

I'm trying to make this table LOOK like a table, but i can't remove the fragment in white as in the picture bellow in the first row:

[image: example]

Code in HTML:

```
<%@ Page Language="C#" AutoEventWireup="true" CodeBehind="testmain.aspx.cs" Inherits="XRSTest.testmain" %>

<!DOCTYPE html>

<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml">
<head runat="server">
    <link href="css/bootstrap.css" rel="stylesheet" />
    <meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=utf-8" />
    <title></title>
</head>
<body>
    <form id="form1" runat="server" style="background-color: white">
        <div class="container mt-1">
            <div class="row">
                <div class="col-8 mt-5 d-inline flex-column h-100 border border-success" style="background-color: lightyellow">
                    Some content
                </div>
                <div id="Info" class="col-4 mt-5 d-inline d-flex flex-column h-100 justify-content-center border border-success" style="background-color: lightgray" runat="server">
                <div class="container">
                    <div class="row">
                            <asp:Table runat="server" ID="PriceInc" class="container bg-white mt-5 mb-3" Style="font-size: 12px;">
                                <asp:TableRow CssClass="bg-primary row" style="font-size: 12px;">
                                    <asp:TableCell>
                                    Incluídos en precio final
                                        </asp:TableCell>
                                </asp:TableRow>
                            </asp:Table>
                        </div>
                    </div>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
    </form>
</body>
</html>
```

Code in C#:

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Web;
using System.Web.UI;
using System.Web.UI.WebControls;
using System.Data;

namespace XRSTest
{
    public partial class testmain : System.Web.UI.Page
    {
        protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            DataColumn col1 = new DataColumn();
            col1.ColumnName = "col1";
            DataColumn col2 = new DataColumn();
            col2.ColumnName = "col2";
            DataColumn col3 = new DataColumn();
            col3.ColumnName = "col3";

            DataTable charges = new DataTable();
            charges.Columns.Add(col1);
            charges.Columns.Add(col2);
            charges.Columns.Add(col3);

            DataRow rows = charges.NewRow();
            rows["col1"] = "ID";
            rows["col2"] = "description";
            rows["col3"] = "0.0";
            charges.Rows.Add(rows);

            DataRow asd = charges.NewRow();
            asd["col1"] = "ID2";
            asd["col2"] = "otherdescript";
            asd["col3"] = "0.1";
            charges.Rows.Add(asd);

            foreach (DataRow row in charges.Rows)
            {
                TableCell inc = new TableCell();
                if (float.Parse(row.Field<string>(2).Replace(".", ",")) < 1)
                {
                    inc.Text = "incluído";
                    inc.Attributes.Add("class", "col-4 justify-content-end");
                    TableRow n = new TableRow();
                    TableCell name = new TableCell();
                    name.Text = "some text";
                    name.Attributes.Add("class", "col-8");
                    n.Cells.Add(name);
                    n.Cells.Add(inc);
                    PriceInc.Rows.Add(n);
                }
            }
        }
    }
}
```

How do i remove that white space/margin/border that is currently there? i've tried iterating with and without "row" class as well as with and without "col" class. Thanks a lot for taking your time here.

EDIT1: i made an example as someone in the comments suggested, this is minimal code with the example requested.

Comment: Can you make a [mcve] using your rendered html and css please

Comment: are you trying to make "Incluídos en precio final" span the entire row? Can't you just change that to a TableHeader instead of a TableCell?

Comment: Pete i will try to make an example as requested on the link you gave.
Leon not at all, just as a cell on top of the table

Comment: @Gonzalo Just so I'm clear your talking about the white space to the right of the green item correct?

Comment: @Gonzalo Here's a code pen try and reproduce your problem I haven't been able to https://codepen.io/anon/pen/xajdYa

Comment: Edited the question with requested format as Pete suggested!

Answer (score 0):

If Im understanding your question correctly.  "Look like a table"  It appears that you just need to add the css "table table-bordered" to either your C# syntax or your html markup. That would give you the look and feel of a table instead of the white space that your image shows.  Hope this helps.

Comment: Added this to CSS in the table and still see the white margin